# The difference of the function keyword and match with in OCaml

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm currently learning OCaml today I came up to this piece of code.

```
let rec tree_to_list acc = function
  | Leaf x -> x::acc
  | Node (t1,t2) -> tree_to_list (tree_to_list acc t2) t1
```

As far as I understand this function does the same than this one

```
let rec tree_to_list2 acc t = match t with
  | Leaf x -> x::acc
  | Node (t1, t2) -> tree_to_list t1 (tree_to_list2 acc t2)
```

However, I do not understand the syntax behind the first function. I find the keyword function confusing. It is supposed to take one argument only such as :

```
function x -> x + 2
```

Could someone please help me understand the syntax of the first function and if any the difference in terms of how both functions are evaluated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, a little confusing, we have 3 function definition syntaxes, and pattern matching on the parameter binding side - yes, you can pattern match left of the equal sign.

Comment: Colin G.D. There's a mooc in english  Introduction to Functional Programming in OCaml (www.france-universite-numerique-mooc.fr). It's still open. He began this week (with an introduction by Xavier Leroy).

Comment: Hi @V.Michel I know about this mooc my teachers are the ones behind it, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Functions in OCaml are defined by giving patterns for the arguments. The common case of a simple variable name (like `acc` in your first function) is just a particular kind of pattern that matches all values.

So, one way to look at it is that `fun` defines a function with any number of arguments that can each be given by one pattern. On the other hand, `function` defines a function with one argument that can be given by any number of patterns.

```
# let dot = fun (a, b) (c, d) -> a *. c +. b *. d
val dot : float * float -> float * float -> float = <fun>

# let geti = function None -> 0 | Some i -> i;;
val geti : int option -> int = <fun>
```

The `fun` form can, in essence, be absorbed into the left hand side of a `let` to give a more concise notation.

That is,

```
let f = fun p1 p2 -> ...
```

can be written as

```
let f p1 p2 = ...
```

So for example:

```
let dot (a, b) (c, d) = a *. c +. b *. d
```

Your first function is using a combination of the two (a concise `fun` and a `function` on the right).

Answer (score 11):

> As far as I understand this function does the same than this one

You are correct in that the two code snippets are evaluated the same.

> Could someone please help me understand the syntax of the first function

As @JeffreyScofield seems to have answered this part very nicely, I'll focus on the second part.

> if any the difference in terms of how both functions are evaluated

The tl;dr is there is no difference and the assembly produced is actually identical. We'll use a simple Fibonacci example to show the assembly emitted both using the `match with` and `function` notations.

```
let rec fib n = match n with
| 0 -> 0
| 1 -> 1
| i -> fib (i - 1) + fib (i - 2)
```

and

```
let rec fib = function
| 0 -> 0
| 1 -> 1
| i -> fib (i - 1) + fib (i - 2)
```

both produce

```
fib:
    subq $24, %rsp
.L102:
    cmpq $1, %rax
    je .L100
    cmpq $3, %rax
    je .L101
    movq %rax, 0(%rsp)
    addq $-4, %rax
    call fib
.L103:
    movq %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq 0(%rsp), %rax
    addq $-2, %rax
    call fib
.L104:
    movq 8(%rsp), %rbx
    addq %rbx, %rax
    decq %rax
    addq $24, %rsp
    ret
.L101:
    movq $3, %rax
    addq $24, %rsp
    ret
.L100:
    movq $1, %rax
    addq $24, %rsp
    ret
```

Note: I intentionally removed the `.align`s and such.

To verify the claim that these produce the same assembly (and are thus evaluated the same), you can simply put each function in a file and then run

```
$ ocamlopt -S fib-with-match.ml
$ ocamlopt -S fib-with-function.ml
```

when you `diff` the two, you should see it return with no difference:

```
$ diff fib-with-match.s fib-with-function.s
$
```

It's very common to have functions that only contain `match` expressions in OCaml, so as @JeffreyScofield said, `function` has an argument that can be used for pattern matching. Therefore, it's effectively syntactic sugar.

Source:

- http://philogb.github.io/blog/2008/08/11/pattern-matching-in-ocaml-and-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

My way to explain the function definition in OCaml:

These are **equivalent:**

```
let name p1 p2 ... pn = expr
let name = function p1 -> function p2 -> ... -> function pn -> expr
let name = fun p1 p2 ... pn -> expr
```

How to memorize it:

- the first is syntactic sugar,
- the second is what it really does internally,
- the third is legacy from caml.

Now `function` takes only one argument, but it is often used like this - these are **equivalent,** you are matching on p3:

```
let f1 p1 p2 p3 = match p3 with
 | []  -> expr
 | ...

let f2 p1 p2 = function
  | []  -> expr
  | ...
```

You see the second version saves some source characters, removing visual clutter. Or more: there is no need to bind a value to p3 without using the p3 variable, because pattern matching is the best binding construct.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is just not naming explicitly its argument.
You can do the same with the function that adds 2 :

```
let f = (+) 2;;
```

That will add 2 to any number and the arg is not explicitly named.